# Internet Explorer Slow with Developer Tools open Angular

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015

I use Internet Explorer while doing development with Visual Studio so that I can get debugging directly into my Typescript in Visual Studio and be able to edit it directly right there.  This normally works well, except that if I ever have to open the developer tools in IE to say inspect styles etc. and the page I'm working on has an Angular ng-repeat (of any size of data) IE gets progressively slower. The more elements in the ng-repeat, the faster it gets slower, until it will finally crash IE and the debug session.

I'm guessing it's some sort of memory leak or something, but was wondering if anyone else encountered this and knew of a work around?